# Copying a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to do a deep copy of a Javascript object using Jquery.extend but I don't  it being copied...

Here is a simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('Hi')
        var obj1 = [{'name':'bob','age':'20'},{'name':'Tom','age':'20'}];
        jQuery.extend(obj2,obj1)
        console.log('Hi')

})
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RQD8y/)

I dont see the second debug stmt printed in the console.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `obj2` first:

```
    console.log('Hi')
    var obj1 = [{'name':'bob','age':'20'},{'name':'Tom','age':'20'}];
    var obj2 = {}
    jQuery.extend(obj2,obj1)
    console.log('Hi')
```

The new array will still be working with the same objects, however. If you want a deep copy (that is, an array with a new copy of the objects inside it), pass true for the `deep` parameter of jQuery.extend:

```
    jQuery.extend(true, obj2,obj1)
```